# Laravel & Jquery - Filled Textbox with Select box to the other field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

How can I achieve this output?

[image]

I want a dynamic dropdown like when I select a value on the dropdown then the textbox should be filled with its connected value `aircraft_id` on the table below automatically

here is my database value example

[image]

so for example i choose `123` on the select  dropdown then the textbox must be filled with `3` automatically, how can i do that?

here is my code, the code is working but it is only getting the same value what i want is to get the another value from the table.

**View**

```
 <span>Aircraft Name</span>
                <select name="aircraft_name" class="aircraftsName">
                  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> Select </option>
                  @foreach ($aircrafts as $aircraft)
                      <option value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}" >{{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}</option>
                  @endforeach

                </select>

                <span>Aircraft ID</span>
                <input id="aircraft_id" type="text" class="aircraft_id">
                <br>
```

**Javascript and Jquery**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.aircraftsName', function() {
        var air_id =  $(this).val();     // get id the value from the select
        $('.aircraft_id').val(air_id);   // set the textbox value

        // if you want the selected text instead of the value
       // var air_text = $('.aircraftsName option:selected').text(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

my Current Output and problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your script

```
$(document).on('change', '.aircraftsName', function() {
    var air_id =  $(this).val();
    $('.aircraft_id').val(air_id)
});
```

what are you doing above code ? what is the value `$(this).val()`

```
<option value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}" >
```

you are assigning **aircraft_registration_number** so this is you need to change like below

`<option value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_id }}" >`

even if you have 1000 records

you can use your array simply

```
@foreach ($aircrafts as $aircraft)
  <option value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_id }}" >{{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}</option>
@endforeach
```

or You need to change your **$aircrafts** array it should be like this

```
$aircrafts = [
           '1' => 'Sample',
           '4' => 'Boieng',
           '3' => '123'
        ];
```

then change your for-each

```
@foreach ($aircrafts as $id => $aircraft)
      <option value="{{ $id }}" >{{ $aircraft }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: okay sir thanks for your answer , I cannot change it to aircraft_id because I need to update two values

Comment: is there any other solution to my jqeury to change its value i cannot change the select option value sir

Comment: @SummerWinter you can use your array as it is plz check my answer i  have edited

Comment: what if i have 100 of data then should i also put 100 array values? what if i added another data on the table

Comment: @SummerWinter chek now